# ADAL library not working with VS2015 Community Edition

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

We have a product in terms of Custom Visual Studio Project templates. Upon installing our addin user can see our custom templates in Visual Studio New project creation window.

During the project creation using our project templates we have an option to get connected to Azure Cloud and need to fetch some data from the cloud service we deployed.

So we are using ADAL library for the same. When user provides details for the Azure it should pop up Azure authentication window and after successfully authentication user can fetch data from the Azure cloud service.

Our code Environment:

We use VS2010 for our actual product code and installer will be created. So All our code we use to create these Custom templates are targeting to .NET version 4.0 and we use Active Directory Authentication Library 1.0.2 nuget package and the ADAL file version is 2.0.1856.0 the same screenshot is attached below.

[ADAL Library Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pq1Dv.png)

Our Custom project templates can be used to create projects in VS2010, VS2013. Now we have to support VS2015 Community Edition for the same.

Issue we are facing:

Our templates are working perfectly fine with VS2010 and VS2013. But when we try to create projects in VS2015 CE we are getting load type exception for ADAL version 2.11.0.0. But in our machine we have registered ADAL Nuget Version 1.0.2 i.e. ADAL file version 2.0.1856.0 as shown above. But the error we get looks little weird because we have neither registered any upper version of ADAL to GAC nor in our code. When we try to create project the moment when user provides all the details and Azure Authentication window should pop up but here it’s not popping up and VS2015 CE is crashing and getting closed.

I have attached the exception details screenshot below.

[LoadType Exception With ADAL in VS2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10ugo.png)

Why ADAL version 2.0.1856.0 is not working with VS2015 as expected? Could you help us on this issue as we are stuck with our release due to this error?

All our projects are targeting to .NET 4.0 and can we get a fix for this issue without upgrading our .NET versions of our projects? Are there any other ways to resolve this issue?

Comment: Adal 2.x requires .net 4.5 support. Adal 1.x is not supported anymore as adal 2.x has been out for more than 2 years.

Comment: Thanks Panwar for your time. We are using the same version since some time but its working fine with VS2010 & VS2013. I Nuget package version is 1.0.2 but the ADAL file version it shows as 2.0.1856.0. If 2.x requires .NET 4.5 how is the same working for us. I was thinking we are using 1.x version of ADAL. Correct me if I Understood wrongly.